# time period SQL count query

Tags: mysql, sql

i;m trying to count elements for some period of time  using the following query

```
select count(*) 
from push_message 
where app_names='AP1' AND
      time < (current_timestamp - interval '30 day')
```

I still get the whole count and not for 30 days , my "time" column will be like

```
time               | 2019-08-22 17:59:02.686915+04
```

what did i missed on my query ? please advise

Comment: I am guessing you want `>=` rather than `<`.  If so, I would classify this as a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this:**

```
select 
  *
from
  yourtable t
where
  /* Greater or equal to the start of last month */
  t.date >= DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY) and
  /* Smaller or equal than one month ago */
  t.date <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```